# Unable to update a particular state using React Reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I am using React Context on my application.

This is in my Provider file:

```js
// Initial State
const initialState = {
  user: [],
  monitors: '',
  loading: true,
  isAuthenticated: false,
};

  function getMonitors(username) {
    axios
      .get(`/api/users/usermonitors/?user=${username}`)
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch({
          type: 'GET_MONITORS',
          payload: res.data.monitors,
        });
        console.log(res.data.monitors); // This returns expected response
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }
```

This is in Reducer file:

```js
case 'GET_MONITORS':
      return {
        ...state,
        monitors: action.payload,
   };
```

And I am calling it in my View file as below:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    getMonitors(user.email);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
```

The problem is that Reducer is not updating state, and I don't see why. All other Provider actions are being updated successfully to state by Reducer, just not this.

And, `console.log(res.data.monitors);` in Provider file just after Dispatch, returns the expected response.

What is that I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working properly and it is updating state as well. The problem was, I was checking the state from React Devtools on Chrome, and it was not showing the updated state.

Then I console.log that particular state in one of the view file, and it cleared my doubt.